# SQL Server : Group By records not on the same day

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a set of tables where we used to maintain transaction histories of bank account.

We have applied grouping on the transaction and get the grouped transactions. This worked fine for normal accounts. I used this query to analyze the users regular transactions which happens on pattern like every week or fortnightly or monthly and it is used to to find the users Salary credit, and living expenses.

When the transactions are based on joint account and if a patterned transaction happens on the same day with same description, the query sums up which is wrong.

Ex:

Husband & Wife works on the same company and gets Salary on 1000 & 500 respectively. The grouping should group 1000 separately and 500 separately. The transaction amount can differ because he or she could get variable pay. Because of this issue, it is calculate pattern wrong. Say if the its fortnightly, it calculates as weekly. Can someone shed some idea to fix this issue.

The requirement is, if a group occurs twice in the same day, it should group them separately.

SCHEMA

```
1. CustomerBankAccountTransactions
Column_name                  Type     
---------------------------- ---------
BankAcounttransactionID      nvarchar 
BankAccountID                nvarchar 
TransactionDate              datetime 
Amount                       float    
IsDebit                      nvarchar 
RunningBalance               nvarchar 
Description                  ntext    

2. CustomerBankTransactionGroupLink
Column_name                Type    
-------------------------- --------
ID                         numeric 
TransactionGroupID         numeric 
BankAcountTransactionID    nvarchar
UpdateUser                 nvarchar
UpdateDateTime             datetime

3. CustomerTransactionGroup
Column_name         Type    
------------------- --------
ID                  numeric 
SubCategoryID       numeric 
GroupName           nvarchar
UpdateUser          nvarchar
UpdateDateTime      datetime
IsDebit             nvarchar
```

The query sample is,

```
SELECT MAX(tg.ID),
       tg.GroupName,
       COUNT(tg.GroupName) AS GroupCount,
       CASE
           WHEN at.IsDebit = 't' 
                THEN 'Debit'
           ELSE 'Credit'
       END AS TransactionType,
       MIN(at.Amount) AS MinimumAmount,
       MAX(at.Amount) AS MaximumAmount,
       AVG(at.Amount) AS AverageAmount,
       MIN(at.TransactionDate) AS FirstTransacionDate,
       MAX(at.TransactionDate) AS LastTransacionDate,
       CASE
           WHEN COUNT(at.TransactionDate) <= 1 
                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(at.TransactionDate), 
                              MAX(at.TransactionDate))
           ELSE (DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(at.TransactionDate), 
                          MAX(at.TransactionDate)) / (COUNT(at.TransactionDate) - 1))
       END AS TransactionInterval,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(at.TransactionDate), GETDATE()) AS DaysSinceLastTransaction,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(at.TransactionDate), MAX(at.TransactionDate)) AS TimeSpan
FROM CustomerBankAccountTransactions AT
INNER JOIN CustomerBankTransactionGroupLink atgl 
           ON atgl.BankAcountTransactionID = AT.BankAcounttransactionID
INNER JOIN CustomerTransactionGroup tg 
           ON tg.ID = atgl.TransactionGroupID 
WHERE AT.BankAccountID = '012083191715294f957d06e-76ad-485a-ad0e-e115a1e479fe'
GROUP BY tg.GroupName,
         AT.IsDebit
ORDER BY tg.GroupName
```

Comment: Please provide the schema.

Comment: Hi Hrishi, I have updated the schema with the question.